# How to define ascending Intergers in function?

Tags: java, android, integer

My question is rather simple but nonetheless I wasnt able to find an answer.
Id like to create a new Integer (or any other data type) every time a method is called like:

```
public void x(){
    int i = 0;
    int num;(plus value of i in its name eg: num1, num2, num3,...)
    i++;
    }
```

Comment: What language do you want javascript or java?

Comment: Please note: Java and Javascript are not the same language, in the same way that Austria and Australia are not the same country.

Comment: Cant you just add a static ArrayList to the function? Also, make sure that this is actually what you want to do.

Comment: oh im sorry im using java

Answer (score 1):

what you're thinking of is called varvars (variable variables) and Java does not support them (thank god - we have reflection)
PHP does though: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

what you probably want is to put your Integers in a Collection: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: If they really want dynamic variable behavior, a HashMap mapping string names to values would work too. If the variables are being referenced by a number starting a 0 though, I agree, and ArrayList is the way to go.

Comment: first of all a big thanks to both of you for the fast response.

Comment: first of all a big thanks to both of you for the fast response. but just to clarify: its not possible to create a variable in java without giving it a static name first? Is it possible to rename a variable later or do I have to create a new one and copy the value of the old into to new one?

Comment: @NicoB. you should erase the difference between variable and collection, and you'll see it provides exactly what you need. No, what you're asking is both impossible and useless.

Comment: ill try my luck

Comment: @NicoB. Like mentioned above, you can use a `Map` or `List` to do exactly what you need. If you want to create a variable called `num1`, just create an `ArrayList` called `nums` (or something), and access the values like `nums[0]`, or `nums[1]`. There's no need for dynamic variable creation.

Answer (score 0):

You should store your int num into the class instead of the method, this wise your variable has object escope and will have its reference anytime you call your method.